# mapping files using readdirsync with es6 modules

Tags: node.js, fs, es6-modules, readdir

In my Node project I'm using es6 imports instead of commonjs' `require()`.

I've found this snippet to map through a folder and insert the files as the second argument to `app.use()`:

```
readdirSync('./routes').map(r => app.use('/', require('./routes/' r)));
```

Can I translate this to es6 import syntax?

Comment: ES2020 `import()` syntax is asynchronous, so no, there is no 1:1 equivalent. I'd rather recommend spelling out the imports, or generate that file in a build step, but if you really want you can still dynamically register routes. Have you tried it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Bergi. 
No, I am not familiar with dynamically registered routes. An alternative I've seen and will probably go with is to collect all routes files in a single file and import that into my main app.js file.

Comment: By "dynamically registered route" I mean the `app.use('/', require(someVariable))` that you're already using. You can of course do `app.use('/', (await import(someVariable)).default)` as well, but make sure to consider what happens if the server is opened before all routes are registered.

Comment: Ah, yes of course. 
Thanks for the suggestion but if this isn't a common/recommended pattern, I think I will revert to something that is (e.g. importing all routes into one file, then exporting that to my main server file).

Comment: It's fine, it's just a bit more complicated than manually importing and registering all the routes

Comment: Can you explain this syntax (with an example maybe)?
`await import(someVariable).default`

Comment: `import(…)` returns a promise that will fulfill with the namespace object of the module. Access the route handler as a property on it under the name that you exported it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
readdirSync('./routes').map((r) => app.use('/api/v1', require('./routes/'+r)))
```